# emacs error in tramp mode

Tags: emacs, tramp

I have setup tramp mode with emacs, have been working using that mode for awhile, recently I start getting following error where I am unable to open any files.

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50sml-mode.el (source)...done [3 times]
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Tramp: Opening connection for toolserver using scp...
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh   -e none toolserver'

Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell
Tramp: Sending command `exec ssh   -e none toolserver'
Tramp: Found remote shell prompt on `toolserver'
Tramp: Opening connection for toolserver using scp...done
byte-code: Couldn't find exit status of `test -e /home/FILE_NAME.py'
```

I have re-name the actual file to `FILE_NAME.py`

**Actions taken:**

I deleted the .tramp_history file but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Try using the `/sshx:` protocol instead of `/ssh:`

Answer (score 0):

- try using the `scpx` or `sshx` protocol instead.
- try `(setq tramp-verbose 6)` and check the output buffer to see what's really happening (`C-h v tramp-verbose` to see the levels), then proceed from there.
- Sometimes, it's because my `ssh-agent` is dead. Restarting it solves the problem.
- Sometimes it's because TRAMP still thinks the connection is somewhat usable when it's not. When this happen, I do `M-x ibuffer * * D RET` to kill all the TRAMP buffers so it starts over.

If none of this works, try to use latest TRAMP from melpa or to reinstall it. TRAMP works pretty fine out of the box, maybe you tweaked something that broke it?